# Pass viewbag to action method using Url.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have view in which I have a Url.Action link. When user clicks on this link, I am redidrecting to a action method. I need to pass viewbag to this method when user clicks on Url.Action link and I need to access this viewbag value in action method where it redirects.

In view:

```
<a class="Border left " id="BackBtn"
                       href="@Url.Action("Search")">
                        <span>@Labels.BacktoQuesstions</span>
                    </a>
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search()
        {

            //Here I need to access the viewbag value from Url.Action method
        }
```

Thanks for the suggestions!!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot access `ViewBag` properties this way. `ViewBag` is used for passing data from a controller to a view (not from a view to a controller)

Change you action method to accept a parameter

```
public ActionResult Search(string id)
{
  if (id != null)
  {
    // do something with the id
  ....
```

and use a html helper to construct the link in your view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Questions", "Search", new { id = ViewBag.SomeValue });
```

Comment: I don't want to change the method signature. I don't want to pass parameters for method. If not href, Can I use the html.ActionLink to pass the viewbag. I need to verify whether the method has been invoked by this actionlink or not.

Comment: ViewBag is a temporary object used on the server side when rendering the view. Once the view is sent to the browser, it no longer exists. The browser cant send it back!. Perhaps explain what you need the value for? And why cant you change the signature?

Comment: I need value to identify that it is been called from this view and load a different method based on it. this method is been used by other methods.

Comment: Then you need to do as I indicated in my answer. If you using the default routing with `... defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }` then you can navigate to the method using `/YourController/Index` (without any parameter) or `/YourController/Index/SomeValue` (in which case you can test the value of `SomeValue` and redirect to to another view (but why not just create the correct action link in the first place)

Comment: Perhaps use sessions for this - you can't use viewbag in this way